# Convert WMD editor content in HTML format

Tags: wmd, wmd-editor

I am very new to using this [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) editor. In a simple way, I am using this editor in my page using ASP textbox with a "wmd-input" class. It is perfectly behaving like a WMD editor.

But when I enter some data and do some formatting like bold, italic, etc. and read the editor's content from the server side, I can see the data in plain text.

Is there any way I can read the data as HTML formatted data?

Answer (score 0):

```
QnaUserClaims.GoldBadgesCount = InsertedUserObj.GoldBadgesCount.ToString();
QnaUserClaims.SilverBadgesCount = InsertedUserObj.SilverBadgesCount.ToString();
QnaUserClaims.BronzeBadgesCount = InsertedUserObj.BronzeBadgesCount.ToString();
QnaUserClaims.Reputat
```